# Flex : stop initialization process

Tags: apache-flex

I'm just trying to stop the process of initialization of my `Application` component to load some SWF file before initialization of children occurs. How can I do this please ?

Comment: Another option might be to use a second class (something extending Group or BorderContainer) as your display root, then do something like this.addElement(new MyDisplayGroup()); inside a creationComplete event handler.  Then your skin SWF (declared in the main application MXML) will be loaded before your actual display gets built.

Comment: @Brian : good idea, I will test it tomorrow ; now I have to go to bed ;)

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much Brian for your suggestion :)